# Pros/cons of Kendo UI Mobile vs PhoneGap vs Native for a corporate mobile app

Tags: web-applications, cordova, kendo-ui, native, mobile-application

Our software development team has been assigned a task to develop a new internal corporate HTML5 mobile application to manage specific business processes and we've been given a task to conduct a research on various existing mobile web technologies and to decide on the best technology to be used for the implementation.

We need to choose one HTML5/Javascript library that we all are going to use and our team leader is pushing for using Kendo UI Mobile library for the project, however one of senior software engineers insists that we have to stick with PhoneGap. A few developers also had suggestions to use Native (i.e. developing an Android native app) instead as opposed to a web app.

I am fairly new to the area of mobile app development and not familiar with those technologies, however have been asked to find out the advantages/disadvantages of those frameworks and how they compare to each other. I was just wondering if anyone who is experienced in using those libraries could briefly outline the main distinctive key features of those frameworks and how they differ from each other (i.e. advantages/disadvantages) and whether any one of them is superior to another and would be more preferable in a particular situation?

Or maybe are there any other mobile web frameworks that would be worth looking into and what are their benefits?

Any reply would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: I think your question is too broad and the wording makes me think you haven't done a lot of research so far; [PhoneGap and Kendo UI Mobile](http://www.telerik.com/phonegap-ui) aren't mutually exclusive, for example; I suggest reading a few articles on HTML5 vs Native vs Hybrid first

Comment: also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/202027

Comment: @LarsHöppner thank you for your feedback, I guess my wording indeed wasn't specific enough and I've slightly corrected it. The thing is we have to stick with only one implementation technology/framework and I just wanted to see how Kendo UI Mobile differs from (compares to) the other frameworks mentioned (since our team leader is pushing for that library). I would really appreciate any piece of feedback or professional knowledge from you with respect to the question. I'm new to this area of dev so any help would be much appreciated. Regards, Alex

Comment: PhoneGap and Kendo UI serve different purposes - one is a framework for building hybrid apps, the other is an HTML5 UI library; so choosing between those two doesn't make a lot of sense if you ask me; and the choice between native and hybrid is mostly about the requirements and resources you want to / are able to spend (e.g. what the devs are familiar with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kendo is a great framework to go with for your mobile or web application.The support provided is great and you can achive native like feel with kendo UI.I'll leave you a link to the mobile app developed using kendo

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.payoda.Insurance

this app has been released in IOS,android and windows store.

Phonegap and cordova are technologies used to build the app developed using kendo or sencha etc.I suggest you develop app using kendo and build it using phonegap.

In native apps you have to code for each platform.Hybrid apps developed using Kendo requires coding once and can be deployed in all platforms

Comment: above url is not available on Google play.Please correct.

Comment: Updated URL https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.payoda.gargash&hl=en  Thanks for notifying